# How to get chargePermissionId without capturing or generating chargeId in Amazon Pay Integration

Tags: vue.js, magento2, amazon-pay

I'm integrating Amazon Pay to my vue js storefront. While placing the order, Magento2 Amazon Pay module needs Session ID and a chargePermissionId to capture the amount. Whenever I authorize using Amazon API v2 Sandbox account, its capturing and generating the chargeID. After this, the state is automatically moving to Completed. Looks like I want it in Open state without chargeId and just chargePermissionId.
Can you help me with What I should change to get this?

```
    paymentDetails: {
        paymentIntent: 'Authorize',
        canHandlePendingAuthorization: true,
        chargeAmount: {
            amount: 50,
            currencyCode: 'GBP'
        }
    },
```

Comment: Generally speaking the configuration you have above is correct.  This is instructing the checkout session to authorize (only) payment asynchronously.  The sandbox environment will only leave the authorization open for 2 days however, so be aware this could impact your testing efforts for capturing open auths.  Once CompleteCheckoutSession is called, the chargePermissionId and ChargeId will be returned for the authorization, however this ChargeId is only the reference needed to capture the final charge amount against the open authorization and does not indicate the payment has been captured.

Comment: Since you are using async payments, I would monitor the IPN messages to see what status changes are occurring there.  Also if you include more details regarding the status change of the charge post CompleteCheckoutSession that would help with additional feedback.

Answer (score 0):

A Charge Permission is a contract between you (the merchant) and the buyer. It represents the buyer's consent to be charged. The Charge Permission is used to facilitate deferred transactions. For simple payment use cases, such as immediate Authorization and Capture, you may not need to use the Charge Permission object at all.

Supported operations:

1. Get Charge Permission - GET https://pay-api.amazon.com/:environment/:version/chargePermissions/:chargePermissionId
2. Update Charge Permission - PATCH https://pay-api.amazon.com/:environment/:version/chargePermissions/:chargePermissionId
3. Close Charge Permission - DELETE https://pay-api.amazon.com/:environment/:version/chargePermissions/:chargePermissionId/close